# Can I take gift money from my wife to buy property?

Tags: india, gift-tax, investment-property

I'm buying a property worth 1cr. 40% by my wife and 60% by me in India, Hyderabad. But i don't want to include her in the apartment registration documents. What are the tax implications if i take the money as gift. If she is gifting the money, can she give a cheque from her account directly to the builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tax implications. One can gift unlimited amount to spouse.